# how to create nested struct in c

Tags: c, struct

I have started to learn C and I am finding that creating complex data structures can be quite challenging!

Here is the background:

I have a created a `struct` in a header file `foo.h` and made its contents public:

```
struct frame {
     char *name;
     int width;
     int height;
     //other stuffs
}

extern const struct frame
     vid_1080p,
     vid_720p;
```

The instances of `frame` are constant and can be accessed from other c flies. `foo.c` look like this:

```
const struct frame vid_1080p = {
    .name                 = "1080p",
    .width                = 1920,
    .height               = 1080,
};
const struct frame vid_720p = {
    .name                 = "720p",
    .width                = 1280,
    .height               = 720,
};
```

I am want to create another `struct` within `struct frame` which elements will be calculated at startup of my program and will be possible to modify this if necessary. I am not sure how to approach this, I have tried this approach below and it does not work.

My failed approach:

I have modified `foo.h` as such:

```
struct frame_calc {
     int ratio;
     //other stuffs
}

struct frame {
     char *name;
     int width;
     int height;
     //other stuffs
     struct frame_calc *calc;
}
```

And `foo.c` is also modified:

```
 const struct frame vid_1080p = {
        .name                 = "1080p",
        .width                = 1920,
        .height               = 1080,
        .calc                 =  malloc(sizeof(struct frame_calc)) //compiler complains here
    };
    const struct frame 720p = {
        .name                 = "720p",
        .width                = 1280,
        .height               = 720,
        .calc                 =  malloc(sizeof(struct frame_calc))
    };
```

And then `init()` is called once at the beginning of my program and it fills out the `calc` structure:

```
void init(void)
{
     vid_1080p.calc.ratio = vid_1080p.height / vid_1080p.width;
     vid_720p.calc.ratio  = vid_720p.height  / vid_720p.width;
}
```

This approach gives me a few compiler errors. I am also not sure how to initialize my nested struct appropriately. Another concern is, I am using `malloc`, that means I will need to free this at the right places. I would like to avoid this. I am sure all the pro c programmers out there know how to tackle this better!

Last question,  how do I access this `ratio` member for `vid_1080p` instance from other c files? I am thinking `vid_1080p->frame->calc->ratio`.

Hopefully, I have managed to explain what I want to do? If not, I would appreciate constructive criticism on how to modify this question better in StackOverflow, given that it is my first question!

Comment: Have you considered using `struct frame_calc calc;` instead, it is much simpler

Comment: @M.M How would you initialize it inside `const struct frame vid_1080p`? for example, I have assigned `.calc  = 0` and then called `init()` to fill up the structures. I have hit seg fault :(

Comment: `.calc = 0` will give a compilation error if you follow my suggestion. `.calc.ratio = 5;` can be used as an initializer

Comment: You say "will be possible to modify this if necessary" but you also say you want it to be `const` ... you should not have both of those as requirements, because `const` means it cannot be modified

Comment: @M.M UpdateI have tried vid_1080p.calc.ratio = vid_1080p.height / vid_1080p.width inside init(), however I am seeing this compiler error: assignment of member ‘raito’ in read-only object. Any ideas?

Comment: @M.M You are right, I think I need to get rid of `const` as I will need to update the values later on.

Comment: Do you really need the `init` function, instead of just doing `.calc.ratio = 720/1080` ?   (BTW that division gives `0` so maybe you need to consider other design changes if that's not what you are aiming for)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `malloc` the `calc` member because an actual instance is embedded - it is not a pointer.

If for some reason you need it to be a pointer then you need:

```
struct frame {
     ...
     struct frame_calc* calc;
}
```

And access would be `var.calc->ratio = something;`

If you are trying to modify the struct after creation (via `init()`) why are the structs `const`? Were you trying to get around the `const struct` issue by making the struct hold a pointer so you wouldn't have to change the pointer but could change the value it points to?

I'd suggest not using const structs:

```
struct frame vid_1080p {
    ...
}
```

Your `init` function can then do `vid_1080p.calc.ratio = vid_1080p.height / vid_1080p.width;` If you really want to enforce constness access the structs via a pointer to a const struct. `const frame *p_1080p`.

Comment: That is correct. I wanted to keep the parent `struct` as constant. And the nested `struct` is made to hold a pointer (My post does not reflect this - I have just edited the post).  However, I am also seeing that it does not work this way because the parant `struct` is  const.

Comment: If I don't use pointer, I won't need to use `malloc`?  In that case how would I allocate memory and assign `ratio` value to the structure instances?

Comment: I have tried both approaches. Using a pointer and without using a pointer. Either case, I have hit seg fault.

Comment: Update: I am not using pointers anymore. So `const` stays. I have tried `vid_1080p.calc.ratio = vid_1080p.height / vid_1080p.width` inside `init()`, however I am seeing this compiler `error: assignment of member ‘raito’ in read-only object`. Any ideas?

Comment: If the struct is const then you can't change it once it is setup - you cannot modify it in the `init()` call.

Comment: But the child `struct` is not `const`.  Only the parent `struct` is. Is that going to be an issue?

Comment: Yep. What you are wanting makes no sense. You want an unchangeable structure but you want part of it to change.